# How to change the storage default location in Scorm xblock

Tags: python, django, openedx

I am using hawthorn version open edX, Also using scorm xblock https://github.com/overhangio/openedx-scorm-xblock for upload the scorm. by default, it is using /edx/var/edxapp/media/scorm/ path. I want to change the storage location.

For this, I have tried two solutions.

**First solution:-**

In the lms.env.json and cms.env.json change the path.

MEDIA_ROOT = /my/new/path/media/

MEDIA_URL = /media/

Also, added below the line in url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It is uploaded successfully in this path /my/new/path/media/, but when I try to get in the LMS, it is showing a 404 error.

**Second solution:-**

As par scorm xblock, We can change to default location by give the path in below code.

```
XBLOCK_SETTINGS["ScormXBlock"] = { "LOCATION": "/my/new/path/media/",}
```

I have added the code in comman.py and scormxblock.py, But it is not working.

Or, Please correct me if I am adding the code in the wrong place.